# Python 3.5 - Quandl error handling

Tags: python-3.x, quandl

Trying to figure out how to handle the error:

```
quandl.errors.quandl_error.NotFoundError: (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02) You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again.
```

Here's a snippet of the code that I would want the exception on:

```
            source = Q.get(query_site, authtoken=secret)
            df = df.join(source, how='outer')
```

I would want to `break` out if I get the error. What would be with my `except` statement? I tried `NotFoundError` but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Not sure if this is a correct solution but it seemed to work. I first imported `quandl.errors.quandl_error`. After importing the module, the `NotFoundError` worked as an exception. If anyone can verify this that would be great.

Comment: don't think this import works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling the `NotFoundError`

```
from quandl.errors.quandl_error import NotFoundError

try:
    source = Q.get(query_site, authtoken=secret)
    df = df.join(source, how='outer')
except NotFoundError as e:
    print('error: {} '.format(str(e)))
```